# Why does my takeWhile fail to work with my Stream

Tags: scala

The following code prints "*1". What's mystifying is if I remove the comment it returns "*4" which is what I was expecting

```
var max = 0
lazy val list: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: Stream.from(2)
list.takeWhile {
  x =>
    max = x
    x < 4
}//.foreach(println)
println("*" + max)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all: the `lazy` in your second line isn't doing anything—you can remove it and get the same result.

More importantly: `takeWhile` is *actually* lazy, in that it just returns another `Stream`, and nothing past the head of that stream will be evaluated until it's needed. Consider the following:

```
val s = Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ > 0)
```

You and I know that `s` is going to be an infinite stream, but if we fire up the REPL and type this in, it's perfectly happy to evaluate it:

```
scala> val s = Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ > 0)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
```

The same thing is happening in your example: the `(Int) ⇒ Boolean` that you've passed to `takeWhile` isn't going to get fed any elements beyond the head of the stream, until something like your `foreach` makes that necessary.

You can see this even more dramatically by adding something like a `println` inside of the `takeWhile` predicate:

```
scala> val s = Stream.from(1).takeWhile { x => println("Checking: " + x); x < 4 }
Checking: 1
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> val l = s.toList
Checking: 2
Checking: 3
Checking: 4
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Clearly the predicate only gets called for the head of the stream, until we force the evaluation of the rest of the stream by calling `toList`.