# How to start a Scala stream some distance "in" (ala takeWhile)?

Tags: scala, stream, lazy-evaluation

The question [Why does my takeWhile fail to work with my Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923999/why-does-my-takewhile-fail-to-work-with-my-stream) makes it clear that `takeWhile()` is lazy:

```
Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_ < 5) //Stream(1, ?)
```

But for that question the solution seemed to be that one could use `toList` to force evaluation as desired. But what if you want, not a list or specific value, but the continuing `Stream`?

It would seem that I could do it by forcing evaluation until I found the desired value and then instantiate the `Stream` again and use `index` but surely there's a better way?

**UPDATE**: Apparently my phrasing was confusing; I wanted the solution provided by `dropWhile`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the continuing `Stream`"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `span`:

```
scala> val (before, after) = Stream.from(1).span(_ < 5)
before: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)
after: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(5, ?)
```

Or, if you only care about "the continuing stream", `dropWhile`:

```
scala> val after = Stream.from(1).dropWhile(_ < 5)
after: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(5, ?)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are looking for `force`:

```
scala> val s = Stream.from(1).takeWhile(_<10)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s.force
res84: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to understand what you are asking for -- as can be seen by everyone answering a different thing. Here's the answer to another possible interpretation: you want the stream starting at a value. Well, in this case, you can do this:

```
scala> Stream.from(1).dropWhile(_ < 5) //Stream(1, ?) 
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(5, ?)
```

Comment: I apologize for the confusing wording; it was indeed `dropWhile` behavior that I was looking for.